# SSRS 2008 - Empty Textbox if condition is true

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I've got a report which includes a column called Capacity and want to return `""` if the result of the above textbox value is the same as the one in the current textbox.

Example;

```
Country      Capacity        Date
USA           100            01/01/2013
              100            08/01/2013
              100            15/01/2013
              100            22/01/2013
```

So in this case I would want to show the first row with the Capacity of 100 and the rest just blank rows as the capacity is the same, is there a way to do this in SSRS 2008 as I don't want to alter the SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `PREVIOUS` function (see [doku](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156372%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) ):

For the Textbox text use an expression to compare the current capacity value to the previous capacity value; if the values are the same display `""`.

```
=IIF(Previous(Fields!FieldName.Value) <> Fields!FieldName.Value, 
     Fields!FieldName.Value, "")
```